# How do i find out in which iframe my selection is to be found?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I have several iframes (editors) on my page.

How do i find out in which iframe my current selection is to be found?

In this editors i have valid html context. This looks like:

```
<iframe id="dynmaical_id">
  <head>
  ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <span>Text</span> //cursor is set somewhere here
    </p>
  </body>
<iframe>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, give details about the context and the language used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out whether the current selection is inside the iframe by checking if `document.activeElement` is set to it. You can then use `document.activeElement.contentDocument.getSelection()` to find out the selection inside the iframe.